# Script to delete files older than a day in Sharepoint document library

Tags: sharepoint, document-library

I need a script which can delete all files which are older than a day and this script needs to be invoked every day automatically in the Sharepoint server.
How can i do this and any hints as how to write the script?

Answer (score 3):

I think an easier way to do it would be to create a site collection policy with an expiration.  Set the retention period for one day.  You can then attach the disposition workflow to your list which acn be used to clean these files up.  You should be able to do all of this without writing any code.

Here is a link with more information about disposition workflow.
http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepointserver/HA101544291033.aspx

Thanks,
Corey

Answer (score 1):

If you really need a script rather than writing code (such as a timer job) then use [Powershell](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_PowerShell) to access the SharePoint .NET objects with a scripting engine. Once you've written the script, set up a Windows scheduled task to run it every day.

In the script follow [Lars' guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/519374/script-to-delete-files-older-than-a-day-in-sharepoint-document-library/520133#520133) on using one of those two query classes. Then from the query results you can obtain a reference to each SPListItem you'd like to delete. Either use [SPListItem.Delete](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.delete.aspx) or [SPListItem.Recycle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.splistitem.recycle.aspx) to remove the item.

Here's an example that uses SPQuery:

```
[System.Reflection.Assembly]::Load("Microsoft.SharePoint, Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c")

$site = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("http://yoursite/")
$web = $site.OpenWeb("Web Title")
$documentLibrary = $web.Lists["Document Library Name"]

$yesterdaysDate = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities.SPUtility]::CreateISO8601DateTimeFromSystemDateTime([System.DateTime]::UtcNow.AddDays(-1.0))
$query = new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPQuery
$query.ViewFields = "<FieldRef Name='Modified' />"
$query.Query = "<Where><Leq><FieldRef Name='Modified' /><Value Type='DateTime' IncludeTimeValue='TRUE'>" + $yesterdaysDate + "</Value></Leq></Where>"
$queryItems = $documentLibrary.GetItems($query)
foreach ($item in $queryItems)
{
    echo $item.Url
    $item.Delete()
}
$web.Dispose()
$site.Dispose()
```

Answer (score 0):

You could create a [custom timer job](http://www.andrewconnell.com/blog/archive/2007/01/10/5704.aspx) in SharePoint using .NET and the [WSS API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc768559.aspx) to do the job. Use the [SPQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spquery.aspx) class to query files by date in a document library. Use the [SPSiteDataQuery](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spsitedataquery.aspx) class if you need to query across multiple document libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Here is C# code to delete only files on SharePoint site which are older than a day, to run this every day you need to create SharePoint Timer Job and add below code inside execute method of timer job.

```
        SPSite spSite = new SPSite("http://YourSiteUrl");
        SPWeb oWebsite = spSite.OpenWeb();
            SPListCollection collLists = oWebsite.Lists;

            foreach (SPList oList in collLists)
            {
                if (oList.BaseType == SPBaseType.DocumentLibrary)
                {
                    SPDocumentLibrary oDocumentLibrary = (SPDocumentLibrary)oList;

                    if (!oDocumentLibrary.IsCatalog && oList.BaseTemplate != SPListTemplateType.XMLForm)
                    {


                        SPListItemCollection collListItems = oDocumentLibrary.Items;

                        foreach (SPListItem oListItem in collListItems)
                        {
                            if (oListItem.File != null)
                            {
                                if ((DateTime.Now - oListItem.File.TimeCreated).TotalDays > 1)
                                {
                                   oListItem.Delet();

                                }


                            }



                      }
                    }
                }
            }
```